# How to make text size bigger in Steam on Crostini?

Tags: steam

I'm using Steam on Chrome OS (Crostini). The text is tiny. How can I make the text bigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit /usr/share/applications/steam.desktop

```
Exec=env GDK_SCALE=2 /usr/games/steam %U
```

In Steam settings, make sure the following is checked:

> Enlarge text and icons based on my monitor size

[image]